# Why won't my SQL results get printed in PHP site?

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

I'm having real problems with this code, Basically I have an external server which I am trying to call and add the data from that into a single PHP data site. However for some reason after reading loads on this subject I still cannot get this to work.

The following code is below, and this is the concept which I have in mind, but for some reason, I am having no luck in getting this to work correctly?

Any help would be much appreciated:

```
<html> 
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
         <?php
            // Determine Yesterday
            date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
            $m= date("m"); // Month value
            $de= date("d"); //today's date
            $y= date("Y"); // Year value
            $yd = date('d', mktime(0,0,0,$m,($de-1),$y)); 
            $ym = date('m', mktime(0,0,0,$m,($de-1),$y)); 
            $yy = date('Y', mktime(0,0,0,$m,($de-1),$y)); 

            $yest = $yy.'-'.$ym.'-'.$yd;
            $cd = date("Y-m-d");

            // Make a MySQL Connection
            ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', '240');

            // Make a MySQL Connection
            $con=mysql_connect("location", "Username", "Password");

            // Check MySQL connection
            if (mysql_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
            }

            $Test= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DB1.Table WHERE date(DateCreated) between '$yest' and '$yest'")   or die(mysql_error()); 

            echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <th> DataField1 </th>
            </tr>"

            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($Test)){
                echo "<tr>
                <th>" .$row['DataField1']. "</th>
                </tr><tr>
                <th>" .$row['DataField2']. "</th>
                </tr>";
            }
            echo"</table>";

            mysql_close($con);
        ?>

    </body>
    <footer>
    </footer>
 </html>
```

I'm sure for some it's a glaringly obvious problem, but I'm a bit of a novice with the database connections. This current code produces nothing on the webpage when loaded.

Comment: [`mysql_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) something you haven't chosen.

Comment: @Fred-ii- he uses in queries "DB1." so it doesn't have to use select db

Comment: @Robert *Oh,* you can do that and not having to use `mysql_select_db`?

Comment: do `echo mysql_num_rows($Test);` and see how many rows are returned.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: select_db just sets the default db. you can ALWAYS use a fully qualified `select db.table.field`-type construct anywhere you want.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks Marc, something I did not know. Can the same be done in `mysqli_`?

Comment: it's an sql thing, nothing to do with the db library you're using. it should work with ANY sql database.

Comment: But it makes the code pretty tightly coupled to the db name. If you select the database using mysql_select_db, then you just have to change it there, if you rename your db, and not in a lot of queries in your code.

Comment: @Hans So it has its pros & cons then.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes you can :) Check it by yourself. mysql_select_db() does juse USE '' and you don't have to execute "use" to work on db. You can also perform queries between tables from different dbs using this syntax

Comment: @Robert I'll surely give it a try, thanks Robert.

Answer (score 1):

Meta-level error:

```
date(DateCreated) between '$yest' and '$yest'
```

is basically a wordy/useless version of

```
date(DateCreated) = '$yest'
```

And if that's supposed to be "yesterday", then all of your PHP date mangling code is pointless. You could do it far easier directly in the database:

```
WHERE date(DateCreated) = (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

And functional errors:

```
        if (mysql_connect_errno()) {
```

This function doesn't exist. mysql_*() functions simply return boolean FALSE, and you'd check it like this:

```
$db = mysql_connect(...);
if ($db === FALSE) {
   die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say that currently hasnt worked, but really interesting advice with the date information/function

Answer (score -1):

For the mysql_fetch_array: `mysql_fetch_array($Test,MYSQL_ASSOC)` or use $row[0] instead of $row['DataField1']. You are getting a regular array but trying to use it as an associative array

Comment: False: fetch_array returns a "both" array by default. fetch_row returns a purely numeric-key array.